# How can I diplay whole text in RichTextBox using preseted font

Tags: c#, fonts, character-encoding, character, richtextbox

in c# I'm trying to display text (from txt file) in RichTextBox and I want display whole text using the preseted font (Arial). When I type the text "test ěščřžýáíé" it displays ok but when I try to set the Text programmaticaly

```
RichTextBox.Text="test ěščřžýáíé";
```

the words/characters are displayed with different fonts (the word "test" is really displayed in Arial). What do I do wrong?

Thanks for any help
Pavel

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the font? I assume you are using the Win Forms RichTextBox. I have managed to produce a very simple application which does what you have described as what you need:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12.0f);
    richTextBox1.Text = "test ěščřžýáíé";
}
```

With a Button button1 and a RichTextBox richTextBox1. When the button is clicked the text appears.